# Load multiple functions from multiple javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, function, onload

I have multiple functions within multiple external JavaScript files that I want to load when the page loads. If I use "body onLoad" then one function always supersedes the other. How do I configure it so I can load each function from each file and have them load as soon at the page does?

I tried combining the files by putting both functions (only have 2 at the moment) into one javascript file, however whenever I use "document.getElementById("clockModule").innerHTML =" to output data to a specific div ID, the data is outputting to a single ID and they overlap one another

Answer (score 2):

When you do `window.onload = function(){ ... }`, what you're doing is assigning a new value to `window.onload`, replacing whatever is assigned to it previously. This means there can only ever be one value. In the same way, `innerHTML` replaces the entire contents of the element.

Instead, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach your event handlers and consider creating DOM nodes and attaching them using [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I have no idea window.onload could only have a single value assigned to it, that makes a lot of sense

Comment: See MDN "`window.onload = function() {
  init();
  doSomethingElse();
};`"

Comment: @Joseph Okay I tried figuring it out myself but I can't is there a more detailed explanation in regards to using addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

During development, it's fine to load several separate .js files.  However, once you're ready to publish to production, you'll want to roll all that .js into one file for performance purposes (and maybe even [minify](https://jscompress.com/) it).  In any case, I always use `DOMContentLoaded` listener like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //do stuff in here.
  if(window.location.pathname === '/about'){
    //do page specific stuff in here.
  }
}, false);
```